# How to centre FontAwesome icons vertically in a list item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am making a list with some text and fontawesome icons. I am able to centre the text vertically, but not the icon. Here you can see what I mean:

[image: What it looks like:]

Here is my code:

```css
.fa-info {
  color: #90A4AE;
  position: fixed; 
/*position is fixed so I can align it to the edge of the page*/
  width: 55px;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 11;
  height: 60px;
}

#sidebar ul {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  left: 70px;
  top: 23vh;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}

#sidebar li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #90A4AE;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'NeutraFaceMedium';
  text-align: left;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-info fa-small"></i>About Us</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to be able to centre the fontawesome icon vertically so it is on the same level as the text.

Thanks

Comment: give it rel pos  and then  top: (box height/2) - (icon height/2)...

Comment: @dandavis I don't really know the height of the icon. I set the font size to 0.8em.

Comment: then half the height is `0.4em`...

Comment: you need to use `position:fixed` on the container (like the UL), not on the icon itself. once you have fixed the container, you can "pan" around the icon bu giving it `position:relative` and top/left/bottom/etc values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the vertical align:
`<i class="fa fa-info fa-small" style="vertical-align: middle">`

Comment: This isn't working sorry. The icon is still aligned to the top and not the middle. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Sorry about that, I always mix up middle and center. Thanks @Garconis

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #sidebar ul {
      width: 200px;
      float: right;
      left: 70px;
      top: 23vh;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: left;
        padding:0; 
        margin:0;
    }

    #sidebar li {
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: #90A4AE;
      list-style-type: none;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: 'NeutraFaceMedium';
      text-align: left;
      -o-transition:.5s;
      -ms-transition:.5s;
      -moz-transition:.5s;
      -webkit-transition:.5s;
      transition:.5s;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    .fa-info {
      color: #90A4AE;
        padding: 9px;
        font-size: 20px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      z-index: 11;

    }
```

JSFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1224/`

Comment: I need the position to be fixed so that I can align the fontawesome icon to the left of the page. Do you know if I can align it to the left of the page without the position being fixed? Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `.fa-info` position and width is what causing the issue. Remove or comment them out and it works great.

```
.fa-info {
  color: #90A4AE;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 11;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: I need the position to be fixed so that I can align the fontawesome icon to the left of the page. Do you know if I can align it to the left of the page without the position being fixed? Thanks for the answer though.